# In Sitecore Personalize, how can I test full stack triggered experiences/experiments?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize

I have created a Full Stack Triggered Experience in `Sitecore Personalize` and now I want to test it before making it Live.

For Full Stack Interactive Experiences and Web Experiences I have a 'Test' or 'Preview' button beside the 'Start' button but I don't have this same testing functionality available for Full Stack Triggered Experiences.

How can I test Full Stack Triggered Experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Stack triggered experiences/experiments cannot be tested before they are made live. A full stack triggered experience must be put live and triggered to test their execution. Once full stack triggered experiences have been triggered details of the execution, including any errors can be seen in the execution report in the operational tab or in the guest timeline.

If a full stack triggered experience is using a decision model, the decision model can be tested using the test canvas.

If your full stack triggered experience is being triggered when the session is closed, e.g. on abandoned cart or session close, you can close the session early by sending a special event by sending the event type as FORCE_CLOSE. Force close events immediately closes a session without having to wait for point of sale session timeout. Force close events are only used for testing, in live websites sessions end on point of sale session timeout.

To easily trigger your full stack triggered experience, you can change the trigger to a custom event for testing e.g. an event with type ‘TEST_TRIGGER’.